# Filtering Data frame in R by single letter with several letters in each column - Capitalization Matters

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a data frame which has several columns and thousands of observations. One of the columns is called "STATE". This column has many combinations of the letters "A, B, H, E, e, C, c". I want to filter this data frame down to only rows that contain a **uppercase** "C" as well as any other letters. I basically want to eliminate rows that do not have **uppercase** "C". I have tried to use something like below without much success:

```
df1 <- filter(df, grepl('C', STATE))
```

An example of a row in "STATE" is "ABEecC" or any combination of these letters. I want to include rows that have uppercase "C" along with any other letters and discard combinations of letters in rows with out "C".

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just do something like? `df$STATE[grep('C', df$STATE)]`

Comment: `filter` statement looks fine

Comment: I'm with @NathanDay, your filter statement works just fine on `df <-data.frame(STATE = c(letters,LETTERS))`

Comment: I believe the problem is that I have combinations of those letters in each row. For example, in the column "STATE", a row may contain "ABEecC" or any combination of those letters. I only want to include combinations of those letters that contain capital C.

Answer (score 0):

`df` is a function name (see `?df`) so I use different name `my.df` your original data frame.  I suggest you to rename it.

```
my.df1 <- my.df[grep("C", my.df$STATE),]
```

@tcash21 gave you almost the correct answer. But it returns back only with the matching elements of the column `STATE`. With `grep("C", my.df$STATE)` the matching rows are selected. `grep` has the default behaviour to return back with a vector of mathcing indices. You can select with the resulting numbers the right rows of your data frame.

`filter` function works with *time-series*.